# Python: How to call a new instance of a class within a method of the class

Tags: python, methods, instance, self

I came across the following problem in Python:

I have a class called `BasebookDataContainer` which is mainly a collection of Dicts.

Within a method of that class, I call a new instance of `BasebookDataContainer` like this:

```
class BasebookDataContainer:  
    def generate_sub_basebook(self, columnlist):  
       ....  
       newinstance = BasebookDataContainer()
```

A lot of strange things happen:

1. `newinstance` automatically is loaded with all the data of the
   "self" instance of the class `BasebookDataContainer`
2. When I change the data of `newinstance`, it also changes the data of the
   "self" instance

Is this normal and is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel. Can you post the code for the `BasebookDataContainer` class? At least all [static properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible) that you've defined in it and its `__init__` method.

Comment: Where do you attach the data members to the class? If you attach a mutable object (a dict for example) in the class definition,  it will be shared by reference across instances. If you don’t want this behavior, attach the dict inside of the __init__ instead.

Comment: How is the `__init__` method defined? Is it decorated as a `@classmethod`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to every body for the feed-backs.
Actually, I had made a mistake:
In the BasebookDataContainer Class, I had declared a data structure containing a list of fields (lists, dicts, strings, etc...), directly in the class definition itself.
As a result, when there were several instances of objects of the same class, all those attributes were stored in the same memory address. It was a mistake of mine, since I have a C++ background.
The correct way to do it:
Do not declare the structure fields in the Class definition (leave the values at None) and allocate memory in the **init**() method of the class.
It works perfectly now.
Lesson learned.